# System.NullReferenceException at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInHeadersCollection()

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've seen this error occur once a day and it appears to be intermittent. We can't reproduce this in order to troubleshoot but the stack trace is being sent via Elmah. Does anyone have any ideas on how we can isolate and stop the below exception from occurring?

The code at Default.aspx.cs:line 12 is:

```
Response.Redirect("Research.aspx");
```

Nothing else is on the Page_Load block.

This is the stack trace:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>       at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInHeadersCollection()
>        at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureHeaders()
>        at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Headers()
>        at
>   System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.IsAsyncPostBackRequest(HttpRequestBase
>   request)
>       at
>   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.HttpResponse_Redirecting(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>       at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse,
>   Boolean permanent)
>       at
>   NielsenNRG.CinesysSuite.WebPortal.ResearchPlus.Default.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Git\Cinesys\WebPortal\ResearchPlus\Default.aspx.cs:line 12
>        at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>        at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>        at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>        at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>        at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>        at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Response.Redirect ("Research.aspx", false);` then the exception is not thrown (but the runtime will continue processing the current request).

Read more: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629